# How to remove \n newline character and replace with \r carriage return in logback?

Tags: java, newline, logback, amazon-cloudwatch

I tried `%replace(%rEx){'\n','\r'}` but logback can't interpret the `\r` it just prints "r" instead. There is a way to get it to read the carriage return value from an envinronment variable by doing `%replace(%rEx){'\n','${MY_ENV_VAR}'}` but that seems really messy to create an entire env variable just to reference a carriage return. Is there a better way to convert all \n to \r? Like through some kind of encoder or config? This is needed because AWS cloudwatch doesn't like newline characters and it teats all new lines from a stack trace is individual log events.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the carriage return? `\\r`

Comment: @SupaJord Yes, that doesn't work either. Logback just doesn't interpret any of that, strings only or use `${ENV_VAR_ONLY}` If I were to put `\\r` in there, `\r` is printed. if I put `\r` in there, `r` is printed.

Comment: hello @Zombies , do you already have the solution for this? can you share if it is working?